# Easy to remember server names

Tags: linux, windows, networking, domain-name-system

I have a small office network running Windows Server 2003

I also have a linux box running a bunch of atlassian applications. (jira, confluence, fisheye)

They are currently accessed using the ip address and port of the application

I want to be able to create a easy naming scheme to remember

wiki.myserver, 
jira.myserver, 
fisheye.myserver

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We did something similar, we ended up just calling them http://wiki/ http://issues/ http://repo/ etc. They were only accessed from the LAN.

My suggestion would be to plan for the future when you might want to separate these applications onto different servers, while preserving the URL's (good URL's don't change).

A simple way to do this would be to use Apache / nginx name based virtual hosts, and proxy requests to your tomcat instance.

If you do this with Apache, use mod_proxy - don't get caught up in mod_jk etc.

Answer (score 0):

A difference from nine years ago when this question was asked and answered is that today it would probably be considered best practice to secure traffic even to internal web services using TLS, effectively ending up with names like https://wiki.example.com, https://issues.example.com, etc.

- If these services are presented to the Internet too, https://letsencrypt.org provides a couple of simple ways to get the necessary certificates for free depending on the technical capabilities of the web server and the DNS provider.
- In an IPv4 deployment with limited externally accessible IP addresses, which unfortunately is still the most common scenario in 2019, the reverse proxy may be configured to use self-signed certificates to secure traffic to its backend servers, while using letsencrypt to provide the necessary certificates for incoming traffic.
- If the services are not supposed to be externally accessible, the best solution would likely be to use self-signed certificates all the way, and provide client computers with the necessary certificate chain to recognize the internal certificate authority.